# Intermittent "You don't have access to this" error with selenium tests running on azure build agent with Azure AD

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, build-agent

I have a solution with some automation tests. Each test calls a Logon() method, which logs a test user in via azure AD, and then each test visits a different page and checks it works.

The Logon method does the following:

- Go to the URL of the site
- Microsoft login box appears
- Enter username of the user, press enter
- Enter the password of the user, press enter
- Microsoft says do you want to set up 2fa (the test user is within the grace period, couldn't figure out how to get past 2fa otherwise)
- Press the ask later button
- Microsoft says do you want to stay logged in?
- Click 'yes', click OK (doesn't matter afaik since every test is completely separate and there are no cookies etc)
- Homepage of the site loads with the user logged in.

This works fine locally, and it works *sometimes* within azure. It runs as part of the PR, I create a PR, which triggers a build agent, which runs the tests.

Generally, 4 of the 6 tests will pass. Not always the same 4.

Getting information out is very hard, so I added some code to take a screenshot of the window and dump it encoded into the exception. When I decode it, this is what I see:

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that sometimes the test passes, and sometimes it errors and produces this. I can't understand why the access would be intermittent. When this error occurs, it doesn't affect all the tests, as I say, just 1-2 of them seemingly at random and they all run together.

Any ideas that might point me in the right direction?